# Install Linux in SD Card

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install my Ubuntu 14.04 into a SD Card, my problem is: Linux don't detect the SD Card (Using the SD Card Dock Reader).

I figure out i can workaround buying a SD card usb reader, it probably would detect it...but is some way i can install it without buying the SD reader?

P.D: SD Card is detected by Windows 10 and no matter what format is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Detected as in at the time you try to boot from it, or at the time you try to write to it? If this is about booting, then you need to tell what boot loader you use (it's not really important what distribution of Linux you use though). I'm not an expert in this area, but I know that lilo bootloader is more modern, and is sometimes advised over grub (which is the default option for most distributions nowadays). You'd need to look into documentation, and perhaps add more tags and information to your question though.

Comment: I can see it in BIOS/UEFI but not in the installation setup somehow

Comment: Oh, I see, well then, you might be better off not using the installation program, which is probably not intended for that anyway. Try following some live-USB creation guide, but use your SD card instead of a USB.

Comment: Funny thing is: I can install it as "Live" but my maxxed persistence is up to 4GB (I guess is because the FAT32 system), anyway to max this partition?

Comment: I'd guess that that's because of FAT32. I wouldn't know how to modify "live" USB layout to get it to utilize more disk space up-front, but you sure can just allocate the remaining space to a new parition, put some other fileystem on it and mount it, say, in fstab. Not the best solution, but would work, I guess.